# 3g USB reciever not connecting

Tags: usb, 3g

First of all Maybe a sorry is needed because I am not sure if this is the right place for this question.

Now, I have a 3g dongle from alcatel named 'x230s' provided by wind(italian internet company) 
It used to work fine on my windows 8.1 machine, but i reinstaled windows 8.1 and it cant conect,

I press connect, program sais it is conecting then the led turns red and discontects directly without any warning. So I can't go on internet

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Check at first if the SIM is still valid, for example try to use the SIM in another cell phone.

Comment: the sim was valid 3 weeks ago before i f*cked up windows :)

Comment: got it, it just started working for no reason